# Curl with authentication in Python using standard libraries

Tags: python, authentication, curl

I'm trying to create the Python equivalent of

`curl -u username:password http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/forces`

as stated here http://www.police.uk/api/docs/authentication/

I've manually logged in through a browser and got the authentication to work

I first tried basic authentication from here:

voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml

This fails with

```
This page isn't protected by authentication.
But we failed for another reason.
```

I then tried from adapting this stackoverflow.com/questions/1990976/convert-a-curl-post-request-to-python-only-using-standard-libary

```
import urllib2

def basic_authorization(user, password):
    s = user + ":" + password
    return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

req = urllib2.Request("http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/forces",
                headers = {
     "Authorization": basic_authorization("username", "password"),
    })

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print f.read()
```

and get:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I read that at stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126/python-urllib2-basic-auth-problem:

'The problem could be that the Python libraries, per HTTP-Standard, first send an unauthenticated request, and then only if it's answered with a 401 retry, are the correct credentials sent. If the Foursquare servers don't do "totally standard authentication" then the libraries won't work.'

linking back to the "This page isn't protected by authentication." error with the basic authentication.

I used their code:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)'
```

but still get error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I'm not sure what to try next.  I am new to programming in Python and using Curl and I am at a loss as to whether I have just got the basics wrong or there is something more complicated going wrong.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Can you try running Fiddler or (whatever http debugging tool is best on your environment) and looking at the http sessions that occur when you access the api from your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've manually logged in through a browser and got the authentication to work

How did you do that?

Did you use FireBug or some other tool to observe what actually happened?

You should probably study what worked before reading too many StackOverflow answers.

Comment: I used Fiddler as mentioned above and it turned out I had obtained a virus that was inteferring.  I removed this and the authorisation now works.  Thanks for the suggestion.